# No entra en la coleccion un addOnCompleteListener

Tags: android

Hoal. Tengo dos colecciones en could firestore. Dinero (con un solo resistro) y Portadores (con mas de un registro).

```
 public void restaurar() {


    mfirestoredinero = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    DocumentReference dRDinero = mfirestoredinero.collection( "Dinero" ).document("1");
    mfirestoredinero.collection( "Dinero" ).document("1").get().addOnCompleteListener( new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                DocumentSnapshot documentdinero = task.getResult();
                if (documentdinero.exists()) {
                    cuotatext.setText( documentdinero.getDouble( "cuota" ) + " €" );
                    cenatext.setText( documentdinero.getDouble( "cena" ) + " €" );
                    tunicatext.setText( documentdinero.getDouble( "tunica" ) + " €" );
                }
            }
        }
    } );


    mfirestoreportadorestotal = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    mfirestoreportadorestotal.collection( "Portadores" ).get().addOnCompleteListener( new  OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot documenportadores : task.getResult()) {
                    if (documenportadores.getString( "cuota" ).equals( "S" )) { sw_cuota++; }
                    if (documenportadores.getString( "cena" ).equals( "S" )) { sw_cena++; }
                    if (documenportadores.getString( "tunica" ).equals( "S" )) { sw_tunica++; }
                }
            }

        }
    });

}
```

En la coleccion Dinero si entra y ejecuta lo que esta dentro de onComplete.
Pero en la coleccion Portadores no entra en onComplete. ¿Porque puede ser?.
Lo que quiero es recorrer toda la coleccion de Portadores para ir sumando lo que hay en lo if.

Gracias.

Answer (score 0):

Ya esta solucionado, el error es mio, entra primero en toda la funcion y despues entra en las colecciones, en sus onComplete, pero me gustaria que lo hiziera y entrara de forma secuencial, porque en la funcion abajop realizo algun calculo con las variables.

Gracias